# Hide mouse position from websites

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, web

Some websites have functions that trigger given the position of my cursor. The one I perceive most typically, and which I find very annoying, is that a site would bring a "Suscribe to our newsletter!" popup when I move the cursor up to close the tab their website is on.

Normally I would expect them only to react to where I *clic*, not where I hover over... with may be some exceptions in very special websites.

Is there a way to make my browser hide the information on where my cursor is (as long as I am not clicking) from websites? I'd be happy with both solutions for Chrome or Firefox. If somehow IE can but the other two cannot, I'd also like to know.

Should I expect this solution to break functionality of other sites in non-obious ways? E.g. will it break Google maps, even though normally input happens while clicking?

Comment: If you are unable to locate an add-in or other software solution, consider to use Control-W to close the tab. This keystroke works for both browsers listed. This is posted as a comment, as it does not answer your primary question (hiding mouse position.)